# En Passant - Usage after one or more move(s)

Tags: rules, en-passant

I was playing chess on an app against a computer, and I could make an en passant after a move from me and the computer.

```
   
   [FEN ""]
   1.e4 h5 2.e5 f5 3.a4 a5 4.exf6 exf5 {Ignore the weird Bishop if you go back in the game. The parser is confused.}
```

Is this possible?

Can the pawn at e5 take the pawn at f5 now after a move each (o more) from the player?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You can take a pawn en passant only on the next move.

See 3.7d, [here](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf).

> A pawn attacking a square crossed by an opponent’s pawn which has
>   advanced two squares in one move from its original square may capture
>   this opponent’s pawn as though the latter had been moved only one
>   square. **This capture is only legal on the move following this advance**
>   and is called an "en passant" capture.